# Want to have + and - sign ends of combo box using html

Tags: html

please let me know the html control for + and - sign. 
for example: for selection control we write like this
"speed-selection selection" likewise want to know for + and - sign.

Thanks,
Deepak

Comment: show the code that you tried

Comment: show us what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

for - sign - and for + sign +

for more details on ascii click [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: <div class="speed-selection selection">Low speed</div>                                  For this line we get combobox with triangle sign on right side of a combobox. Please let me know the code to create combobox with + and - sign at the end of combobox.

Comment: can u plz tell in a clear way or show your code i try to help you. so draw your need in the paint(combo box structure) and post the image it helps to go further

Comment: so i guess it is related to css class you are applying please share css class code named "speed-selection"

Comment: .speed-selection {
                        width: 46%;
                        float: left;
                        position: relative;
                        display: block;
                        margin-top: 10px;
                    }
This is the css code for speed selection